# Meesage not appear on application startup?

Tags: android, message, startup

I need to set message on application startup which i fetch from database. i fetch data   from database    and need to show it on application startup but it only show the "msg0".
I don't understand where is the problem in my code. Please give me some hint and reference.
Here is my code for reference..

```
Random r = new Random();
  SharedPreferences pref =    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  Editor ed =pref.edit();
  final List<ObjectiveWiseQuestion> LocWiseProfile= db.getAllTipsNTricks();

  for (final ObjectiveWiseQuestion cn : LocWiseProfile)
  {
     for( i=0;i<=counter;i++)
     {
         ed.putString("i",cn.getTips());
         // ed.putString("0",cn.getTips());
     } 

      ed.commit();
  }
  String msg = pref.getString(r.nextInt(i)+"", "none");
  Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then you are over writing values in shared preference editor.

It should be,

```
for( i=0;i<=counter;i++)
     {
         ed.putString(""+i,cn.getTips());
         // ed.putString("0",cn.getTips());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

values are  being overwritten so follow user370305's way, but there are some issues still exists,issue is due to you are fetching values of preferences, as String msg = pref.getString(r.nextInt(i)+"", "none"); outside of inner for loop, so I assume that i has been declared outside of for loop too, which is not being changed anywhere, so outer loop will only show i value, which is declared outside the block you have been provided, which I think is field of class

Comment: ed.putString("i",cn.getTips()); here i is being key and cn.getTips() is the values for the same key i for everytime in for loop.